# Part advice for Audi A4 B8 door actuator

Tags: audi, door, a4, actuator

I have Audi A4 B8 (2.0 Diesel)
I need to replace the right side rear car door's actuator. The part codes are so confusing, with pre Nov 2009, post Nov 2009. I found it very difficult to pin point the date of manufacture. I'm looking to buy online from car parts websites.

I found two types of parts one with Central Locking and the other doesn't mention about central locking. My car has central locking with a keyfob. I'm not sure which one to buy. One has 6 pins and the other has 7 pins.  Please can someone advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum post](https://www.audiworld.com/forums/s4-b8-platform-discussion-134/where-do-i-find-build-date-2800421/#post24104274), you should be able to find your date of manufacture:

> Look inside the drivers door jam, below the latch near the bottom of the main car body, see below example. It is also stamped inside your maintenance book and inside the wheel well where the spare tire is located.

Here's the image which was in the forum as well as an example:

[image]

Here you're looking at the date just below the "MFD".